# How to assign multidimensional array in PHP 7.4?

Tags: php

I am trying to assign a multi-dimensional array in PHP 7.4. I am switching from PHP 7.2 to 7.4 and not sure how I can fix this.

```
$model->a = $model->a ?? [];
$model->a->b = $model->a->b ?? [];
```

I am getting the error:

> Attempt to assign property 'b' of non-object.

Comment: first line -> assigning a array to attribute `a`, line 2: trying to access property `b` of `a` which is an array... i mean, neither in php 7.2 this code will work

Comment: and also, "ho to fix what"? you don't say anything about what you want to achieve

Comment: @Berto99 I need to store a value in $model->a->b-c = {some value}

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

If `$model->a` doesn't exist then you set it to an array, but then attempt to set `$model->a->b` but `a` is an array not an object.

So you either need to assign an object, substitute another class for `stdclass` if needed:

```
$model->a = $model->a ?? new stdclass;
$model->a->b = $model->a->b ?? new stdclass;
$model->a->b->c = 'some value';
```

Or assign an array as you are but then access it as an array:

```
$model->a = $model->a ?? [];
$model->a['b'] = $model->a['b'] ?? [];
$model->a['b']['c'] = 'some value';
```

However, for an array you don't need to do all of that as array assignments are dynamic.  Just this works fine:

```
$model->a['b']['c'] = 'some value';
```

As for the switch from PHP 7.2 to 7.4, this wouldn't have worked in 7.2 either, you must have a difference in error reporting between the two.

You might also look to see if the [__set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic method can help you.